# Can I specify kernel-weight specific learning rates in PyTorch?

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, learning-rate

I would like to set specific learning rates for each parameter on their lowest level. I.e. each value in a kernels weight and biases should have their own learning rate.

I can specify filter-wise learning rates like that:

```py
optim = torch.optim.SGD([{'params': model.conv1.weight, 'lr': 0.1},], lr=0.01)
```

But when I want to get a level lower, like that:

```py
optim = torch.optim.SGD([{'params': model.conv1.weight[0, 0, 0, 0], 'lr': 0.1},], lr=0.01)
```

I receive an error: `ValueError: can't optimize a non-leaf Tensor`
I also tried specifying a learning rate that has the same shape as the filter such as `'lr': torch.ones_like(model.conv1.weight)`, but that also didn't work out.

Is there even a way to do this using `torch.optim`?

Answer (score 2):

I might have found a solution. As one can only input the whole weights and biases of a Conv Layer, we need to insert a learning rate having the same shape as the weight/bias tensor.

Here is an example using `torch.optim.Adam`:

```py
torch.optim.CustomAdam([{'params': param, 'lr': torch.ones_like(param, requires_grad=False) * lr} 
    for name, param in model.named_parameters()])
```

Then we have to change a line in the optimizer itself. For that I created a custom optimizer:

```py
class CustomAdam(torch.optim.Adam):
   def step(self, closure=None):
       ...
       # change the last line: p.data.addcdiv_(-step_size, exp_avg, denom) to
       p.data.add_((-step_size * (exp_avg / denom)))
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple trick is to create a new tensor called `learning_rate` which has the same size as the model. Then when you are applying the gradients, you multiple the `gradients` tensor with the `learning_rate` tensor. Please let me know if this works for you.

Comment: This is very limiting, as you can't specify a scheduler for example

Comment: That may work, but I think I found an easier solution